# ng-repeat repeating by letters wise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have multiple level json that need to show using ng-repeat but i am getting issues

**JSON**

```
$scope.product =  {
    "product": [
        {
            "name": "0001",
            "tagline": "Scrub peached 60% cot 40% poly\r\ns/s v neck scrub uniform w/ 1 chest pkt"
        }
    ],
    "sizes": [
        "XXL",
        "XXXL",
        "XS",
        "XL",
        "S",
        "M",
        "L"
    ],
    "colors": [
        {
            "name": "WHITE",
            "image": "/kalypso/commonsController.do?param=imageLoader&imageName=1239378389537_white1.JPG"
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "big": "/kalypso/commonsController.do?param=imageLoader&imageName=2010_08/1281620375516_UT01.jpg",
            "small": [
                "/kalypso/commonsController.do?param=imageLoader&imageName=2009_07/D0001-b.jpg"
            ],
            "thumb": "/kalypso/commonsController.do?param=imageLoader&imageName=2010_08/1281620375516_UT01.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.productsImages =  $scope.product.images[0].thumb;
$scope.productsImgSmall =  $scope.product.images[0].small;
$scope.productsImgBig =  $scope.product.images[0].big;
$scope.productsColors =  $scope.product.colors[0].cname;
$scope.productsColorsImages =  $scope.product.colors[0].image;
$scope.productsSizes =  $scope.product.sizes;
$scope.productsName =  $scope.product.product[0].name;
$scope.productsTag =  $scope.product.product[0].tagline;
$scope.productsPrice =  $scope.product.product[0].price;
$scope.productsId =  $scope.product.product[0].prdId;
console.log($scope.productsColors);
```

It is repeating the color name each word and if array length is zero I am getting duplicate error messages. Please help on this.

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=color%20in%20productsColors&p1=string%3AT&p2=%22T%22

Comment: show your HTML, can't really help otherwise

Comment: There is not enough code to determine the problem. Please include your view HTML and the relevant code from your Angular controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
instead of array [i] value use like this 
$scope.productsImages =  $scope.product.images;

HTML

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="prd in productsImages">
    {{prd.thumb}}
</li>
</ul>

use repeat function for all key

another Example 
 $scope.data.colors = $scope.product.colors
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="color in product.colors">
    {{color.name}}
 {{color.image}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would look into `track by $index` if you do not have a unique id on your json object

```
item in items track by $id(item)
```

or

```
item in items track by $index
```

if you want angular to deal with it